# Join with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to use group by with join on below data:

statistics:

```
| id | user_id| date|
```

users:

```
| id | name | age|
```

My query which doesn't return table users:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(time_to_sec(date)/60) as mins 
from `statistics` 
JOIN user ON users.id = statistics.user_id 
WHERE 1 and user_id=8 group BY user_id
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Do you get "wrong" result, or is an error raised?

Comment: Is date a date or time?

Comment: The `WHERE 1 and...` is not necessary since you have another condition in the where clause. Could instead be `WHERE user_id=8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN, GROUP BY on three tables to get totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242121/sql-join-group-by-on-three-tables-to-get-totals)

Answer (score 3):

Table name in Join is wrongly mentioned.
it should be users not user as per your table definition.

Answer (score 1):

Typo mistake I think

```
JOIN user ON users.id = statistics.user_id
```

Try this

```
JOIN users ON users.id = statistics.user_id
```